# singular or plural verb x articles

Tags: grammar

Which of these is correct

The preposition is the hardest part in english

Prepositions is the hardest part in english

Prepositions are  the hardest part in english

Preposition is the hardest part in english

Comment: You haven't learned much English if you don't yet know that a singular noun takes a singular verb and a plural noun a plural verb - also, that _English_ needs a capital letter.

Comment: *[english](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/english#Noun)*: *"1. Spinning or rotary motion given to a ball around the vertical axis, as in billiards or bowling."*, *"2. An unusual or unexpected interpretation of a text or idea, a spin, a nuance."*. But even some natives don't know how [their own language](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/English#Proper_noun) is spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Of the offered options, option 1 and option 3 are both grammatically correct and have approximately equal meanings.